# How do I prevent my Perl script from echoing what is typed into the terminal while it's running?

Tags: perl

How do I prevent my Perl script from echoing what is typed into the terminal while it's running?

I tried messing around with `system("stty -echo");` and then running `system("stty echo");` at the end, but it still displays what I type once the script ends. I've been playing around with this test script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

system("stty -echo");

for (1..15) {

    print "$_\n";
    sleep(1);

}

system("stty echo");
```

This could mess up the terminal if the second system called is never reached (maybe use an `END` block, but that's not guaranteed to work either). This would also be Unix only and my script is run on Windows too.

I also found the module `Term::Readkey`, but I would prefer not bringing in any other modules.

I also tried just closing `STDIN` but that didn't work either.

What makes this problem easier is that I don't need to read `STDIN` at all during execution, I can just ignore it.

I don't have much experience with this type of problem, hopefully it's easier than I'm making it out to be. Thanks!

edit: I'm on Perl 5.10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Re: "it still displays what I type once the script ends": Isn't that because your Perl script never reads that input, so it's still on the buffer when the script ends, so the shell reads it, and since by then you've run `stty echo`, that causes it to be echoed? It seems like if you want this input to be silenced, you would need to read it before running `stty echo`. (You can use `scalar <>` to read a single line, or `<>` to read everything until the next EOF.)

Comment: I assume you already read "How do I ask the user for a password" in the Perl FAQ? http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-ask-the-user-for-a-password%3f

Comment: @Nemo, yup! I have already. I wasn't really sure how `ioctl()` works or if that would help solve my problem.

@ruakh if I do `<>;` before the last system call that only takes care of 1 line. if I do `while(<>){}` it hangs. If I do `undef $/; <>;` it also hangs.

Comment: @Nemo as far as passwords go I also ran into IO::Prompt which didn't seem to help me but I figured I'll leave that here for future reference.

Comment: Look on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) for terminal handling modules.  Or, simpler, look amongst the `Term`-related core modules in [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-T.html).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/~jstowe/TermReadKey-2.30/ReadKey.pm):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadKey;

ReadMode ( 'noecho' );
my $password = <STDIN>;
ReadMode ( 'normal' );    #Back to your regularly scheduled program
```

Unfortunately, it's not a standard module. And, I've had some problems with this on Windows.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, I found this module but I would really prefer not to bring in any other modules, so I'm looking for another way to do it.

Comment: @Matt What about using the `POSIX` module? It's be included in Perl since at least 5.8.8. That should allow you to set iocntrl and turn the echo off.

Comment: I got it to work using POSIX::Termios to set cbreak mode and then turn backed to cooked at the end. Also use <STDIN> to read everything so it's not printed when the script ends. I lost the link I used to figure this out throughout my frantic googling but it's similar to this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20can%20I%20read%20a%20single%20character%20from%20a%20file%3F%20From%20the%20keyboard%3F